# How to filter only last reply from total email thread

Tags: case, singleemailmessage, case-comment

I have a requirement to update case comments based on email responses from Emailmessage.

I created a trigger on email message working well.But, now it is creating case comments of an email with whole thread.

But is there any possibility to filter only last reply.

```
public class CaseComments {
    public static void InsertCaseComments(List<EmailMessage> CaseTriggers){
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order' Limit 1].Id;
        List<CaseComment> cc= new List<CaseComment>();
        CaseComment ccc = new CaseComment();
        Map<Id, Case> mapOfCase= new Map<Id,case>();
        set<id> parentids=new set<id>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<CaseTriggers.size();++i)
        {
            if( CaseTriggers[i].TextBody !=null && CaseTriggers[i].ParentId != null)
            {
                parentids.add(CaseTriggers[i].ParentId);
            }
        }
        if(parentids <> null && !parentids.isempty())
        {
            for(case c:[Select id,recordTypeId from case where Id =:parentids])
            {
                mapOfCase.put(c.id,c);
            }
        }
        for(Integer i=0;i<CaseTriggers.size();++i)
        {
            if(CaseTriggers[i].ParentId != null)
            {
                if(mapOfCase.get(CaseTriggers[i].ParentId).recordTypeId == recordTypeId && CaseTriggers[i].TextBody !=null )
                {
                    ccc.CommentBody=CaseTriggers[i].TextBody;
                    ccc.ParentId=CaseTriggers[i].ParentId;
                    cc.add(ccc);
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('Size of CaseComments '+cc.size());
        If(cc <> null && !cc.isEmpty())
        {
            Insert cc;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

to achieve this, you have to break the email thread using string methods to get the latest email.

hope this helps.

Comment: But in my case, they have dynamically replied so, I am unable to set up string methods

Comment: i know, but in your emailMessage trigger you are getting email body which you have to filter it out.